# Adjustbox around an align* environment

Tags: align, adjustbox

I want to put an adjustbox around an align* environment such that the entire align* environment is scaled down to have a height of .1\textheight.
I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{adjustbox}{max height=.5\textheight, max width=\textwidth}
\parbox{\linewidth}{
    \begin{align*}
        many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
    \end{align*}
}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

but this doesn't seem to work, i.e. the code is compiled but the align* environment is not at all scaled. 
I get this:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: please show a complete document that shows the problem, as it is the align won't be scaled if it is already less than .1\textheight

Comment: It is not already less.

Comment: I edited my question and included a complete document.

Comment: If I choose e.g. .25\textheight, it seems to scale down to .5 of the actual text height...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what is happening I modified your example as below.

The typeout shows

```
550.0pt,275.01346pt,270.7204pt
```

so the *height* of the alignbox has been scaled to half of text height but it was vertically centred so it has almost equal depth and the end result is more or less `\textheight` again.

`adjustbox` has a `max totalheight` key for exactly this use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\sbox0{\begin{adjustbox}{max height=.5\textheight, max width=\textwidth}
\parbox{\linewidth}{
    \begin{align*}
        many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
         many \\
        many \\
        lines \\
        go \\
        here \\
    \end{align*}
}
\end{adjustbox}}\usebox0
\typeout{\the\textheight,\the\ht0,\the\dp0}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean `max totalheight` ?

Comment: @blk er yes, I'll edit

Comment: Cool, thanks! So yeah, using `max totalheight` did exactly what I had in mind. Thanks again!